# Animating Audi Lamp Sequence

Tags: animation, node-editor, emission

I am trying to animate a lamp sequence for an Audi tail light.

[image]

As you can see now, I divide the lamp object into separate objects (short red bar-shaped objects),
I created an animation by adding an animation that turns on and off to one object and placing a time difference.

I think you can achieve the same effect more conveniently without dividing objects by using nodes.
But the problem is not knowing how to do it.

I want to create an animation in which the bars turn on one by one, without dividing the object into one object.

Additionally, if you know, please teach me how to create an animation where the long horizontal bar under the short bar smoothly turns on.

example video : https://www.youtube.com/shorts/hZaJGqJ2w0g

Looking forward to the answers from the experts.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way I see with geometry nodes would require modeling the segments in geo-nodes as well. It could be done, instead of my curve line node you could model a curve and put the rest of the node tree on there. Only getting the orientations of the light segments right may be a challenge.

Animating a single segment is easy with the setup below. Animate the Plane position to light up a different segment. Or animate the number of adjacent segments by animating the Planes scale.
To animate multiple non adjacent segments you can add more Planes, but that will also require more nodes to track them so they can be added to the selection input of the set material node.
The big challenge for me was finding out I had to use the realize instances node for the selection on the set material node to work.
Make sure the Plane(s) are not rendered by deselecting the little camera next to them in the top right of the screen.

[image]

I was playing with this a bit more and accidentally discovered animating multiple segments can be done by adding shape-keys to the Plane object and animating them.
[image]
To do that:
select the Plane and, in edit mode, duplicate the vertices (a to select all and shift d) but do not move them, and keep them selected.
In Object mode, in the mesh tab on the bottom right of the screen, add the "Base" and "Key 1" shape-keys by hitting the + sign next to the shape-keys twice.
Now with the Key 1 selected tab back into edit mode and move the new set of vertices e.g. to the far right.
You can animate by keyframing the shape-key value.
Create as many separate duplicate sets of vertices with their own shape-key as you need.